# Iterating over the values of $@

Tags: bash, special-variables

I would like to iterate over the arguments given to a bash script, for example:

```
./bash_script file1 file2 file3
```

`$@` gives me all the files given to the script but how do I iterate over the files?

I would like to `cat` each file and remove the contents using `awk` (I know how to do that, it's the unpacking of `$@` that's got me confused).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to **double quote** it as in `"$@"`.

```
foo(){
   printf ' ->%s\n' "$@";
}
foo "a b" c "d e"
```

is equivalent to:

```
printf ' ->%s\n' "a b" c "d e"
```

If the `$@` in the above is *not* double-quoted, then you'll get:

```
 printf ' ->%s\n' a b c d e
```

due to word splitting on `$IFS` characters ( `$IFS` defaults to `' '$'\t'$'\n'`, i.e. a space, a tab, and a newline )

---

**$@ vs. $***

Double quotes work like this for any **@-expansion** on any **array**:

```
$ foo=( "a b" c "d e" )
$ printf ' ->%s\n' "${foo[@]}"
   ->a b
   ->c
   ->d e
```

In contrast, ***-expansions** (e.g., `$*`, `${foo[*]}`) will use the first character of `$IFS` to join the items of an array into a single string:

```
$ foo=( "a b" c "d e" )
$ ( IFS=:; printf ' ->%s\n' "${foo[*]}" )
 ->a b:c:d e
```

which, if left unquoted, will again split on this very IFS character:

```
$ foo=( "a b" c "d e:f:g" )
$ ( IFS=:; printf ' ->%s\n' ${foo[*]} ) 
 ->a b
 ->c
 ->d e
 ->f
 ->g
```

---

**Trick for iterating over $@ in for-loops:**

The `"$@"` array is special. If you want to iterate over `"$@"` in a for loop, then you can abbreviate

```
 for variable_name in "$@"; do
   ...
 done
```

as

```
 for variable_name; do 
 done
```

as skipping the `in something` part of a `for` loop implies `in "$@"`.

This works even in POSIX-only shells too (**dash, bourne shell**) which don't have array variables but support `"$@"` and `"$*`.

Comment: Nice example. Summarizes the usage well :)

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over them, you use a double-quoted `$@`, along the lines of:

```
for arg in "$@" ; do
    echo "--> ${arg}"
done
```

The `for arg in "$@"` could also be written as `for arg` (or even `for arg in`) since the `bash` man page states:

> `for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done`
>
> blah blah blah
>
> If the in word is omitted, the for command executes list once for each positional parameter that is set.

However, I prefer the explicit variant.

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax: testprog.sh 1 2 3 '4 5' '' '6 7 8' "9"
--> 1
--> 2
--> 3
--> 4 5
--> 
--> 6 7 8
--> 9
```

---

And, just as an aside, your comment about using `cat` and `awk` to modify the files may bring down the wrath of the "useless use of `cat` award" crowd :-)

If you're thinking about something like:

```
cat "${fspec}" | awk 'do something'
```

then `cat` is totally unnecessary. You can instead use:

```
awk 'do something' "${fspec}"
```

I'm don't usually worry about the (small) inefficiencies of running an extra process but some people do.